# Regex match dynamic pattern

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string I need to parse using Regex (or Match):

```
SomeTextHereThatIWantToIgnore: <First Month.104.yyyy-mm-dd> <Last Day.2.yyyy-mm-dd>"  OR SomeTextHereThatIWantToIgnore: "<BadVerb.104>"
```

There may be one, two or three strings (all on one line) that I want to parse.  In each case, I want to grab everything between the "<" and ">".

So, in the first example, I want to grab the "First Month.104.yyyy-mm-dd" and "Last Day.2.yyyy-mm-dd".  In the second example, I'd want to grab the "BadVerb.104".

Any Regex gurus out there that can show me how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

The basic regex to get text inside angle brackets without capturing the brackets is

```
(?<=<)[^>]+(?=>)
```

Use `Regex.Matches` to get your matches.

```
var matches = Regex.Matches(str, @"(?<=<)[^>]+(?=>)");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following (with an `s` modifier for multiple line matches):

```
(?s)(?<=&lt;).*?(?=&gt;)
```

See [DEMO](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3F%3C%3D%26lt%3B).*%3F(%3F%3D%26gt%3B)&i=SomeTextHereThatIWantToIgnore%3A%20%22%26lt%3BFirst%20Month.104.yyyy-mm-dd%26gt%3B%20%26lt%3BLast%20Day.2.yyyy-mm-dd%26gt%3B%22%0D%0ASomeTextHereThatIWantToIgnore%3A%20%22%26lt%3BBadVerb.104%26gt%3B%22%0D%0A)

Answer (score 0):

Try : `&lt;[\s\S]*&gt;`

[\s\S] captures any whitespace character or any non-whitespace character so together they will capture anything between the `&lt;` and `&gt;`.

See [here](http://regexr.com/3b1o1)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you stribizhev, I didn't know about the Matches collection.  I ended up doing a simple pattern:

```
[<]([^>]+)
```

that is, look for a "<" and then grab everything that isn't a ">".  The matches collection is the part I was looking for.  I iterated the Match collection and was able to further parse the resulting string and get what I wanted.

Thanks to Sami, Karthik and Walker (that one looks simple too).

Comment: Great, then please consider accepting and upvoting my answer since it proved useful to you. This regex is basically the same, but there is no use placing `<` inside a character class as it is not a spacial character in .NET regex.